# How to sort a unordered list of custom objects based on some condition in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, comparator

```
@Data    
public class DocumentObject {
        public String current;
        public String next;
    
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Unordered list of objects
            List<DocumentObject> list = Arrays.asList(
                    new DocumentObject("pnp","xyz"),
                    new DocumentObject("z","pnp"),
                    new DocumentObject("123","d"),
                    new DocumentObject("xyz","123"));
            //Expecting ordered list to be returned based on some conditions
            System.out.println(sortingLogic(list));
                    
        }
    
        private static List<DocumentObject> sortingLogic(List<DocumentObject> list) {
            if (list.size() > 0) {
//THIS APPROACH NOT WORKING :(
                  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<DocumentObject>() {
                      @Override
                      public int compare(DocumentObject o1, DocumentObject o2) {
                          int index1 = list.indexOf(o1.getCurrent());
                          int index2 = list.indexOf(o2.getNext());
    
                          return Integer.compare(index2 , index1);
                      }
                  });
            }
            return list;
        }

//My Expected output
[{"z","pnp"},
{"pnp","xyz"},
{"xyz","123"},
{"123","d"}]
```

so the logic should be like first object must be {"z","pnp"} as current("z") there is no object where next is ("z"), so it should be first object after sorting.
Then last object after sorting should be {"123","d"}, since there next("d") , there doestn exist any object whose current("d"), so its last object.
The remaining objects are sorted in the middle based on their next and current properties.

How can i acheive this?

Comment: A simple comparator won't work here because there's no way to tell the relationship between item A and item C until they're properly ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a comparator to sort them, this solution considers this as an ordering problem and re-orders the list into a new list in *O(n)* time.

First, it builds a `Map<String, DocumentObject>` from the input list. Next, it gets all the keys of the map as a Set (all `current` values in the list of `DocumentObject`s) and then removes all the `next` elements from the set. This leaves only one element in the set which will be the root or first element (since it didn't have any DocumentObject instance with its value as the `next`). Thinking in graph terminology, this element is the only element whose *in-degree* is 0.

Finally, starting from the root element, we build the ordered list (using the auxiliary map) by traversing the elements as per the `next` value of the current (previous) element.

```
private static List<DocumentObject> sortingLogic(List<DocumentObject> list) {
    Map<String, DocumentObject> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(DocumentObject::getCurrent, Function.identity()));

    Set<String> allCurrent = new HashSet<>(map.keySet());
    map.values()
                .forEach(documentObject -> 
                        allCurrent.remove(documentObject.getNext()));

    // The only 'current' value which is not present as next in any of the other entries
    String root = allCurrent.iterator().next();
    List<DocumentObject> orderedDocumentObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    orderedDocumentObjects.add(map.get(root));
        
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String next = orderedDocumentObjects.get(i - 1).getNext();
        orderedDocumentObjects.add(map.get(next));
    }
    return orderedDocumentObjects;
}
```

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toList())` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @shmosel I don't quite get your point. The map's key is `current` and we are looking to get the entry whose current is not present as `next` in any of the other entries. I guess the map has to be constructed in a different way (with `next` as key?) to incorporate your *filter* logic.

Comment: I think you're right, my bad.

Comment: I wouldn’t use a Stream operation for modifying `allCurrent`. Rather use, e.g. `map.forEach((s, do) -> allCurrent.remove(do.getNext()));` or `map.values().forEach(do -> allCurrent.remove(do.getNext()));`

Comment: And why are you starting with `i = 1`, just to have to use `i - 1` in the loop? Why not start with `i = 0` and use `get(i)`? Then, you don’t have a problem with the `i < list.size()` condition…

Comment: @Holger Updated to not use a stream for modification. IMO, running a loop from `0..size - 1` vs `1..size` is subjective

Comment: It’s not subjective. You start with a list of size `1`, so your loop `for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); …` will not do anything because `1 < list.size()` is `false`. So you have a wrong loop *and* the necessity to use `get(i - 1)` inside the loop. In contrast, `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); …` will do the right thing in combination with the simpler `get(i)` inside the loop.

Comment: @Holger I think you're confusing `list` with `orderedDocumentObjects`. And personally I think the stream+map+forEach was cleaner.

Comment: @shmosel indeed, wasn’t not obvious that this loop referring to `list` isn’t iterating over `list` at all. And it doesn’t even have to use indices as it only retrieves the element it just added in the previous iteration. Why not, e.g. `List<DocumentObject> orderedDocumentObjects = new ArrayList<>(); DocumentObject o; for(String s = allCurrent.iterator().next(); map.containsKey(s); s = o.getNext()) { o = map.get(s); orderedDocumentObjects.add(o); }` Anyway, in which regard do you consider a Stream that operates via side effects cleaner than a `forEach` that also requires half the code?